# Stripping leading character from an alphanumeric string using php

Tags: php

I've got several strings of the type id1, id2, id125, id1258, etc.

What I want to achieve using php is to strip the word "id" from those strings and get only the numbers in **integer format** in php.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these strings only begin with the string `id`:

```
$number = intval(ltrim($number, 'id'));
```

Comment: This really just trims off as much `i` and `d` left-padded as possible, but `id` does only consist of the two letters, so...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace` like this:

```
preg_replace('/\D/', '', $your_string);
```

Where `\D` represents anything not a number. So it is replaced with an empty string leaving you with just number.

**Example:**

```
$string = 'id1258';
$string = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $string);
echo $string;
```

**Result:**

```
1258
```

Comment: @TheNewbie: It would be `\d`. The `d` lowercase then. Check out: http://codepad.org/zDwWyAtI

Comment: In the hurry I forgot the "+", the point being to eliminate non-digits only from the beginning (in case the string is using other format, I prefer to get an invalid answer ASAP): '/^\D+/' => 1258

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good case for a simple `substr`:

```
$number = intval(substr($string, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

If all strings begin with `id` then just make it simple:

```
$num = intval( substr( $string, 2 ) );
```